# SSRS: Group Totals need to be displayed together

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I've a report which is Grouped by Book ABC and then grouped by State to display the total of Qty.

[image]

Is it possible to display the Group totals all together at the bottom of the report ? Something like below:
[image]

Here is my Report Design:

It is a table within a table.
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is there a table within a table?

Comment: I'm showing you only an example of my report. The exact report has a lot of other data other than Book in the main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with an **Adjacent Group**.

With data similar to yours (adding an extra *Book*):

[image]

I have a simple table, grouped by Book, which looks and acts like you'd expect:

[image]

[image]

Now, in the designer I will add an Adjacent Group, adjacent to the existing *Details* group, grouped on *State*:

[image]

Which looks like:

[image]

Now, within each *Book* I have two repeating groups, one that shows each detail row, then one that shows each *State* in that *Book* scope:

[image]

This seems pretty close to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Ian. The idea of Adjacent Grouping helped. I got the exact results needed by adding the Adjacent Group State1 to State instead of details in the inner table.